# Powershell v5.1 not working on server 2016 using a wild card for users directories

Tags: powershell

I have a script that works when I use it on win 10 VM and using a static location with Get-ChildItem -Recurse.

when I put this on the server and trying to delete all the cache files in Teams that consume space over time, where Microsoft says to delete these if you need to reclaim space.  having a 2Tb limit of Windows can be challenging.  the location is something like, "E:\storage\userfirst.last\Microsoft\appdata\teams\system worker\cache"  (this is just an example) however when I use the wildcard "*" in place of the user aka "E:\storage*\Microsoft\appdata..." when I try to see the information of Get-Childitem -Recurse it does not work.

also, I found out you can't call several folders as a network location, so I commented that out.
also, I had issues calling the .csv for local file locations.  again, I wonder if that has to do with the wildcard calling many user locations.

the end result I was going for, was to run this script daily or weekly and delete anything residing in the cache folder older than today, so it would not try to delete an active cache file.

I obviously don't know what I am doing here, I am not a programmer, and after looking for several days and trying several things, I am still stuck, and this does not work.

I could just do a very simple CD to the path with the wildcard, use recurse and delete everything, however I was trying to make this a bit more user friendly for the sysadmin so it they wanted to add other locations to delete everything, they just need to add to the CSV folder locations and also print the output of what is happening to a file so we know what was deleted.  I tried to create an -OutFile however that did not work either, so I just used the transcript which works every time.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

here is the script I am using.

```
START
# Start Transcript logging
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\testfolder\Transcript.txt"

# Set the network folder location
#Set-Location "E:\storage\*\Microsoft\appdata\teams\system worker\cache"

#Get Todays Date
$Now = Get-Date 

# Import the CSV file with all locations of files to delete.
#$TargetFolder = Import-Csv "C:\TestFolder\deletelocation.csv"
$TargerFolder = "E:\storage\*\Microsoft\appdata\teams\system worker\cache"

# Iterate through each folder path and delete all files later than today.
ForEach ($file in $TargetFolder) { Get-ChildItem -Recurse
    if ($LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-1)) {
        Remove-Item -Path $file -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}

#ending Transcript logging
Stop-Transcript
END
```

I was expecting that everything in the cache folder older than today would be deleted.

for some reason it is not working, I expect the wildcard is failing, I see not errors when running the script in sections, its not showing the childitem in all the folders.

is there a better way to do this?

thank you,

Comment: I think you mean `ForEach ($file in $TargetFolder | Get-ChildItem -Recurse) {`

Answer (score 0):

> `#Get Todays Date`
> `$Now = Get-Date`

This *doesn't* get today's date in the sense of getting the *start of the current calendar day* - it gets the *current point in time*, i.e. the calendar day *as well as the current time of day*.
`(Get-Date).Date` returns the start of today's calendar day.

> `ForEach ($file in $TargetFolder)`

Leaving the typo aside (`$TargerFolder` rather than `$TargetFolder`), given that `$TargetFolder` contains a *string*, this results in *one* iteration, with `$file` containing that string.

With [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) output, as implied by the commented-out line in your question, you'd need to refer to a *property* of the imported objects, e.g. `$TargetFolder = (Import-Csv "C:\TestFolder\deletelocation.csv").Path` if the target paths are in the `Path` column of the CSV data.

> `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`

Given that you're not providing additional input to this statement - neither via *arguments* nor *the pipeline* - this recursively enumerates all files and subdirectories in the *current directory*.

Also, since you're neither capturing the output from this command nor piping it to another command (via `|`), it *prints to the display*.

> `if ($LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-1))`

`=` performs *assignments* in PowerShell, not *equality comparisons*; use [`-eq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-eq) for the latter.

In the context of an [`if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_If) statement, using an *assignment* causes the *assigned value* to be implicitly interpreted as a Boolean, which, based on the [rules of PowerShell's to-Boolean coercion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Booleans), is *always* `$true` in your case.

More fundamentally, you were probably looking for `-lt`, the [less-than operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-lt) in your comparison.

---

Given the above, I *presume* you're looking for something like the following, assuming that the target folders in the CSV data are in column `Path` (adjust as needed):

```bash
$startOfYesterDay = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date

(Import-Csv 'C:\TestFolder\deletelocation.csv').Path |
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
  Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt $startOfYesterDay |
  Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [**`-WhatIf`** common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above ***previews* the operation**. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- The above deletes both *files* and *subdirectories* (recursively) from the target directories (folders); to limit deletion to *files*, add `-File` to the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) call.

Comment: Thanks for the assist,  the import is not working, I just commented it out and just used teh Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Users\....-Recurse | Where-Object LastWriteItem...  and that seems to work.  the CSV file had the path in the first col.  when I ran the import-csv, it just shows the files in the directory where the CSV file resides.

Comment: @user23663231, my answer assumed that the CSV column of interest is named `Path`. Assuming your CSV is well-formed, the implication is that the actual column name in your CSV file is different. If you get the name wrong, the `Get-ChildItem` call receives `$null` as input, which is effectively ignored, and the current directory is targeted.